# zip/compress/tarballing or whatever it's called files on the front-end (browser)

Tags: javascript, html

My job is to make an HTML input where a user can select to upload *"multiple things"* at once, all are accepted, *"multiple things"* could be images with videos, or could be images with folders. or anything (literally).

The problem is, **how?**
I've been thinking of a way of doing it, I've already read other questions on stackoverflow, I've read the question of the person who asked a similar question to mine, then folks replied to him to use **JSzip**. but.. I the answers are quite complicated, and are not directly answering my question, they're showing how to zip files on the front-end *for the sake of downloading the zipped file*.
I don't want that. my goal is to zip the files on the front-end, and just hit the upload button, and on the server I'll have a zip file that I can extract and play with.

This is how I was thinking of **how** to do it and how it should.

just before I finish writing this question, here is an example, a user clicked on the file input on his browser and a window showed up asking him to select the stuff that he wants to upload
[click me to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWdvE.png)
the user now selected the following:

```
-── folder1
│   ├── myVideo1.mp4
│   └── myVideo2.mp4
├── folder2
│   ├── innerFolder
│   │   └── anything.gif
│   └── something.png
├── myImage1.jpeg
├── myImage2.jpeg
└── myImage3.jpeg
```

- I need the exact same structure above, this is why I believe I should zip them (I believe I should, not 100% sure) because I need the folders too.
- the user didn't compress anything and just selected the files and folders he wants, he hit the upload button, the browser compressed/tarballed/...or any term you want the selected stuff and POSTed the zip/(or whatever its) file to the server.
- I can now extract everything from this file and safe them the way I want in the server.

## The end of the question,

---

I've taken a look at the

```html
  <input type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory />
```

but the problem with this is that I can't select files with folders at once, I'll have to select only folders. I don't want that.

**probably** the answer is with **JSzip**, but it doesn't seem that easy? I've tried to read their documentation and I couldn't understand anything there. I'm not 100% sure actually what is exactly JSzip and how it works. but you get the idea.

Comment: [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples.html) seems pretty straight-forward to me.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, okay, how to do it with JSZip? ️

Comment: You'll probably need to use a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to get the data from the file(s) selected.  Then you can build the zip and use [`zip.generateAsync`](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/write_zip.html) to get the file and then upload it (possibly via `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest`).  Maybe something like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#example_uploading_a_user-selected_file

Comment: The `<input type="file">` element can support either files OR folders, but not both.  If you want both, you'll need 2 elements, one for each.  Drag and Drop is a different thing.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I got the idea, thanks brother, I know this is going to take a lot of time, but could you please write a complete answer on this?

Comment: _Drag and Drop is a different thing_ nice point.

Comment: @YaYa I can try to make an example of this...

Comment: @RocketHazmat, thank you ️️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take all the selected files/folders and add them to a ZIP file (using [JSzip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)).

Using `<input type="file" webkitdirectory>` and `<input type="file" multiple>`, you can allow a user to select file(s) or a folder.

You need multiple elements, as you can either upload a file or a folder, but not both with one element.  NOTE: You cannot have `multiple` with `webkitdirectory` (and yes `webkitdirectory` works in Firefox, see: https://www.caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlinputelement_webkitdirectory).

So, when a file/folder is selected you can add it to the ZIP file, then once everything you want is added, you can click a button to upload it.

Here's an example that lets you select files and folders to add to a zip.  The "upload" button will just download the file as I cannot upload to your server from here.  (NOTE: The `saveAs()` function may not work in the example.)

```js
let zip = new JSZip(),
  // Used to show the file(s) selected
  fileNames = document.getElementById('zipData');

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('upload')).forEach(u => {
  u.addEventListener('change', e => {
    let files = e.target.files;

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      let file = files[i],
        name = file.webkitRelativePath || file.name,
        fileName = document.createElement('li');

      // Append the name to the list
      fileName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
      fileNames.appendChild(fileName);

      // Add the file to the ZIP file
      zip.file(name, file, {binary: true});
    }
  });
});

document.getElementById('zipUpload').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // ZIP up all the files and get a blob
  zip.generateAsync({type: "blob"}).then(blob => {
    let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      formData = new FormData();

    // Add the blob to the data to be sent to the server
    formData.append('zipFile', blob, Date.now() + '.zip');

    ajax.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
      let progress = Math.floor(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
      console.log('Uploading: ' + progress + '%');
    }, false);

    ajax.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
      if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
        console.log('done.');
      }
    }, false);

    ajax.open('POST', 'https://your.url', true);
    
    // We can't actually upload from here, so just download it instead
    //ajax.send(formData);
    saveAs(blob, Date.now() + '.zip');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.5.0/jszip.min.js" integrity="sha512-y3o0Z5TJF1UsKjs/jS2CDkeHN538bWsftxO9nctODL5W40nyXIbs0Pgyu7//icrQY9m6475gLaVr39i/uh/nLA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.5/FileSaver.min.js" integrity="sha512-Qlv6VSKh1gDKGoJbnyA5RMXYcvnpIqhO++MhIM2fStMcGT9i2T//tSwYFlcyoRRDcDZ+TYHpH8azBBCyhpSeqw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form id="zipUpload">
  <input class="upload" type="file" multiple>
  <input class="upload" type="file" webkitdirectory>
  <button type="submit">
    Upload your ZIP
  </button>
</form>

<ul id="zipData"></ul>
```